# Get labels from different levels of hierarchical clustering

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I am working on implementing *cluster adaptive learning*, as proposed in this [paper](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~djhsu/papers/hier.pdf). To implement hierarchical clustering, I used the following:

```
X = sp.hstack((title, abstract), format='csr')
Z = ward(X.todense())
```

If this was to create a dendrogram like this:

[image: dendogram] (from the above mentioned paper)

I can then use the following line:

```
clusters = fcluster(Z, k=2, criterion='maxclust')
```

to get the classes (ie. 2 or 3 from the diagram) to which each `X` belongs to represented as a 0 or 1.

**How can I split the groups so I get labels from multiple levels for each X. For example, how can I get a list of the  classes each X belongs to from either 2, 4 and 9 or from 3, 5 and 6.**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @user1767754 See **bold** section. Is the question still unclear?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
fcluster(Z, height, criterion='distance')
```

where level is an integer (0, 1, 2, ... ) that indicates what [cophenetic distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cophenetic) is allowed within a flat cluster.

> The cophenetic distance between two objects is the height of the dendrogram where the two branches that include the two objects merge into a single branch

This means:

- height = 0 does nothing, you get single-point clusters, one for each original value. Not so useful.
- height = 1 performs first-level merges, those between original entries
- height = 2 performs second-level merges, those between first-level clusters.

I generated some linkage Z on 10 elements and ran

```
[fcluster(Z, height, criterion='distance') for height in range(5)]
```

to illustrate this:

```
  [10,5, 3, 1, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 2]   <- level 0, everyone separate
  [6, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 1]   <- 6 clusters
  [4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1]   <- 4 clusters
  [3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1]   <- 3 clusters
  [2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]   <- 2 clusters
```